# Left join + aggregate functions resulting in incorrect values

Tags: sql, join, aggregate

It feels like there is a very simple solution but I am new to SQL and have been struggling with this for a while.

I am working on joining two tables so that I can map the cost center in one to its associated product group in another. There is a parent child relationship here with product group as parent and cost center as child.

I am ultimately trying to see the spend data, currently only available by cost center in table 1, by the parent product group categorization. Prior to the join, I see the correct dollar value by cost center. After the join, the number dramatically increases and is incorrect.

Table 1 (purchase orders): cost_center_id, amount_ordered
Table 2 (employee plus): cost center_id, product_group_name

Below is a simplified sample of the query I am working with.

```
SELECT
po.po_cost_center_id,
ep.product_group_name,
SUM(po.amount_ordered)

FROM purchase_orders po

LEFT JOIN d_employee_plus ep on po.cost_center_id = ep.cost_center_id and ep.ds = 
po.ds

WHERE
po.ds = (select max(ds) from purchase_orders)

GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: If second table has multiple rows per record in first - the rows with `amount_ordered` will be repeated corresponding amount of times.

Comment: can you share sample data from your tables, current output and expected output? @Ryan

Comment: I was able to solve my problem with a CTE. @GuruStron was correct that I was joining on a table with multiple rows per record. I was really only trying to leverage the table's hierarchy for a mapping so a CTE cleaned this right up.

Answer (score 0):

My take here is that you have duplicate rows because you're not aggregating on both the columns you're joining on. I may be wrong, though try using the following:

```
SELECT po.po_cost_center_id,
       ep.ds,
       ep.product_group_name,
       SUM(po.amount_ordered)
FROM      purchase_orders po
LEFT JOIN d_employee_plus ep 
       ON po.cost_center_id = ep.cost_center_id 
      AND ep.ds = po.ds
WHERE po.ds = (SELECT max(ds) FROM purchase_orders)
GROUP BY po.po_cost_center_id,
         ep.ds,
         ep.product_group_name
```

For more troubleshooting, if you can provide some sample data, I may help you further.

Does it work for you?